# How to return values from external javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, submit, external

I have a function in an external java script file and I dont know how to call and return the value that my function returns in text properly. When I click place order, I want the values to be calculated by my function and then the final value to be displayed underneath the place order box. I can get my function to alert if I enter nothing but I can't get it to return my final value- what am I doing wrong?

```js
function sum2()
{
      var one = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
      var two = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
      var three = document.getElementById("book_3").value;

      if ((one == "")||(two == "")||(three == ""))
      {
        alert ('Error', 'values missing');
      }
      else
      {
         var sum1 = one * 19.99;
         var sum2 = two * 86.00;
         var sum3 = three * 55.00;
         var sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

         document.getElementById('output').value = sum;
         document.write(sum);
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Work</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="container">
     <h2>Order Books Online</h2>
     <form action="" method="post" id=”frm”>
       <fieldset>
       <table border="0">
         <tr>
           <th>Book</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>
           <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Basics of C++</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_1" /></td>
           <td>$19.99</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Program Development in Perl</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_2" /></td>
           <td>$86.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Advanced JavaScript</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_3" /></td>
           <td>$55.00</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       <br /><br />
       <input type="submit" onclick="sum2(); return false;" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
       </fieldset>
      </form>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, its working, output is displaying on last.

```js
function sum2()
{
      var one = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
      var two = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
      var three = document.getElementById("book_3").value;

      if ((one == "")||(two == "")||(three == ""))
      {
        alert ('Error', 'values missing');
      }
      else
      {
         var sum1 = one * 19.99;
         var sum2 = two * 86.00;
         var sum3 = three * 55.00;
         var sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

         document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sum;
        // document.write(sum);
        }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Work</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="container">
     <h2>Order Books Online</h2>
     <form action="" method="post" id=”frm”>
       <fieldset>
       <table border="0">
         <tr>
           <th>Book</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>
           <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Basics of C++</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_1" /></td>
           <td>$19.99</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Program Development in Perl</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_2" /></td>
           <td>$86.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Advanced JavaScript</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_3" /></td>
           <td>$55.00</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       <br /><br />
       <input type="submit" onclick="sum2(); return false;" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
       </fieldset>
      </form>
     </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what I want, except, I do not want a prompt box to display the result, only in text directly underneath the button

Comment: Prompt box removed, check it now

Answer (score 3):

The use of `document.write()` doesn't seem to be what you'd want here.  (And, honestly, should be avoided in general anyway.)

However, this *will* do what you want:

```
document.getElementById('output').value = sum;
```

All you need is an HTML `input` element which has that `id` (which your HTML is currently missing):

```
<input type="text" id="output" />
```

(Additionally, your JavaScript is missing a closing `}`, which is a syntax error.)

Once you have that HTML element and remove the `document.write()` call, this should be outputting the value correctly.

---

If you want to output to something other than another `input` element, then you wouldn't use `.value` but something more like `.innerHTML` instead:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sum;
```

with an element such as:

```
<span id="output"></span>
```

---

As an aside regarding terminology, this isn't "returning" the value from the function.  "Return" has a very specific meaning when it comes to functions, it's when the function itself results in a value using the `return` keyword, passing that value back up the stack to the code which called the function.

This function is writing a value to the HTML, but it's not returning anything.